# Problem with the program to check whether every even index contains an even number and every odd index contains odd number of a given list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

guys. I've just started to learn to code and I have chosen Python, so my questions here are going to be rather basic :)
So, I had to write a Python program to check whether every even index contains an even number and every odd index contains odd number of a given list. This was my solution:

```
def check_the_list(a):
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        if a[i] % 2 == 0 and i % 2 == 0 and a[i + 1] % 2 == 1 and (i + 1) % 2 == 1:
            output = True
        else:
            output = False
    return print(output)


check_the_list([2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 7, 6, 3])
check_the_list([2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 7, 6, 4])
```

The PyCharm says that the output is False for both lists, even though, as you can see, the last element is different.
Therfore,  can someone explain to me what is wrong with my code?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here.  First, you need to fix the logic of your conditional statement according to this pseudocode: if (number AND its index are even) OR (number AND its index are odd).  Second, the way you have structured your code, the value of your output variable will flip back and forth between True and False until you reach the end of your list, then the function returns only the condition of the last item.  So if the last item happens to be an even number at an even index, it will return True even if the preceding numbers did not meet the criteria.  This is not what you want.  You have a more restrictive criterion where you want every single number to meet this condition.  This is how you do it:

```
def check_the_list(a):
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        output = True
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0 and i % 2 == 0) or (a[i] % 2 == 1 and (i) % 2 == 1):
            continue
        else:
            output = False
    return output
```

A much more efficient implementation would be to use the not operator and return False as soon as a number does not meet the criteria:

```
def check_the_list(a):
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        if not ((a[i] % 2 == 0 and i % 2 == 0) or (a[i] % 2 == 1 and (i) % 2 == 1)):
            return False
    return True

print(check_the_list([2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 7, 6, 3])) #True
print(check_the_list([2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 7, 6, 4])) #False
```

Answer (score -1):

As you can see when i = 7 output is false. therefore, both list return false.

```
list one output :
0 True
1 False
2 True
3 False
4 True
5 False
6 True
7 False

list two output :
0 True
1 False
2 True
3 False
4 True
5 False
6 False
7 False
```